# Upload image from MemoryStream rather than directly from hard drive

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

```
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {                                                   
            bitMap.Save(stream, System.DrawingCore.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            bitMap.Dispose();                                
            await Context.Channel.SendFileAsync(stream, "Text");                
        }
```

Real quick cuz I can't find the answer specifically. I am taking an image from my hard drive, applying text to the image and uploading it to the server. It's just for meme-related stuff.

Problem is, I don't want to have to save it to hard drive before uploading it. I'd rather keep it in the MemoryStream. The result here is it uploads the image as if it were a file transfer instead and the image is not shown unless people download it first.

I figure it's because Discord is not differentiating what the file is in the stream and instead simply sending it as a fire transfer.

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify file name with extension which identifies file content, without that API does not have information what type of file you are sending:

```
await Context.Channel.SendFileAsync(stream, "image.jpeg", "Text");
```

Answer (score 1):

I apologize but I seemed to have accidentally stumbled upon my own answer. In case anyone else has this problem I will answer it to help them out.

```
await Context.Channel.SendFileAsync(stream, "Text");
```

The second parameter is the caption for the file. Depending on the file format you chose during the Bitmap.Save(), type the file extension after the caption. Text should be Text.jpg in my example.

Seems doing that will tell Discord to upload it as an image instead of a file transfer.